# How to display hybrid forms in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I designing forms (not a SPA template) that does the CRUD operations to manage a user's preferences.  On all forms I also need to show the latest list of user preferences on the right side of CRUD forms.

I wonder if the controller should have the standard Index, Edit, Insert, etc method, then in the Insert view call a child action to Index method to list the latest preferences? Or should I have a ViewModel that contains both the individual record to be inserted and a List with a hybrid form bind to the View Model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great question I face every week. I love the concept of MVVM, but I choose to tackle it with child actions.

I love child actions because

1. I can pass values to them from my Model and have them adapt
2. I can call them with JQuery .load() and pass a value from a dropdown or other user input.

Their versatility make child actions Partials my first choice for dependent behaviors.